# If/then statement and sql count rows

Tags: sqlite, python-2.7

I'm attempting to perform an if then statement based on the results of a sql count rows query. The query is returning the proper values however the if/then statement seems to be ignoring the returned value of the sql statement.

Here is my code.

```
import sqlite3

# Define SQL statement to select all Data from Column Name
sql = "SELECT Count(*) FROM arbtable WHERE Name = ?"

book_name = 'Winged Coat'

class PriceCheck(object):
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()


    def query(self, arg, cardname):
        self.c.execute(arg, cardname)
        return self.c

    def __del__(self):
        self.conn.close()

def display():
#Connect To DB and Get Price of Matched book.
    getbookprice = PriceCheck("arbbase.sqlite")
    for row in getbookprice.query(sql, ([book_name])):
        if row == 0:
            print 'no row was found'
        else: 
           print 'Yep its there!'
            print row



display()
```

The program here is that my result, as evidenced by "print row" at the bottom of the code is 0. Since it is zero according to my if statement it should print 'no row was found', but instead it prints the else statement value of 'yes its there!'

I've researched extensively and think that possibly the fetchone statement is what I need, but I can't seem to figure out how to properly apply this to my code to test it.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Sour Jack

Comment: Why are you running a loop on a single count value to start with.

Answer (score 0):

First try a standalone python program to test if you are able to retrieve the value, then refactor according to your requirement:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('arbbase.sqlite')
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("SELECT Count(*) FROM arbtable WHERE Name = ?",('Winged Coat'))
rows = curs.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print row[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The query `SELECT COUNT(...) FROM ...` always* returns a single row.
That row contains the number of rows that were counted.
This number might be zero, but then it's still a number contained in one row.

To check the result of the COUNT(), you must check this value:

```
for row in curs.execute("SELECT COUNT(..."):
    if row[0] == 0:
        print 'no row was found'
    else: 
        print 'There are {} rows with this name'.format(row[0])
```

(It might no be very intuitive to use `for` to fetch a single row. You can use `row = curs.fetchone()` instead.)

<sup>* except when using GROUP BY</sup>